# Can I filter a data frame based on ID's in other frames?

Tags: r

I have three sample data sets (one from 2016, one from 2017, and one from 2018) all include a personal identification number.

The tables are all laid out like this: (sample set from 2016)

```
MLBID  Speed16   SpinRate16 
1111   98.32      2500
```

I want to filter each table based on whether the MLBID is present in the 2017 table AND the 2018 table. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: One way would be to do a full join on the tables and then use `na.omit`.

Comment: @hmhensen the issue with doing that is I am trying to do a regression. Would you then suggest Subsetting the data based on certain columns?

Comment: Semi-join? We'd need to see data samples to be able to help more specifically

Comment: As camille said, sample data would be useful. I'm not sure what you're aiming to do, but if you don't want to remove any observations, after the join, you can create a new column with a dummy variable that tells you whether an MLBID has observations for each year using `ifelse`.